# iOS drawing arcs not working as expected

Tags: ios, quartz-core

I'm trying to draw a simple arc with Quartz Core but I'm not getting the expected result.

My arc is a basic 0 degrees to 90 degree arc (counter-clockwise direction).

I have this code here:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, self.strokeColor.CGColor);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, self.center.x, self.center.y);

    CGFloat radius = self.bounds.size.width / 2.0;

    CGContextAddArc(ctx, self.center.x, self.center.y, radius, [MathTools degreesToRadians:0], [MathTools degreesToRadians:90], 0);

    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

}
```

Note: `MathTools` is just a convenient class I create for converting degrees to radians and vice versa, the implementation for `degreesToRadians:` is:

```
+(CGFloat)degreesToRadians:(CGFloat)degrees
{
    return degrees * M_PI / 180.0;
}
```

But instead of seeing a white arc inside my purple circle, all I see is white dash:

[image: no arc in circle]

I'm trying to get it to look like this:

[image: expected result]

### Edit

Based on answer given by rmaddy, my new code looks like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, self.strokeColor.CGColor);

    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, self.strokeWidth);

    CGFloat radius = self.bounds.size.width / 2.0 - self.strokeWidth;

    CGContextAddArc(ctx, CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds), radius, [MathTools degreesToRadians:0], [MathTools degreesToRadians:-90], 1);

    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
}
```

Not sure if this helps anyone else but based on what I see here, it seems Apple's angle positive and negative direction is not the same as mathematics. From memory, mathematic +90 degrees is anti-clockwise, but Apple's +90 degrees seems like clockwise.

Comment: Use the debugger and check all of the values. Realize that `self.center` is relative to the superview, not `self`. So that part is wrong.

Comment: Wow, that is news to me. @rmaddy do you want to add an answer and also explain why self.center doesn't refer to the current view this `drawRect` method is being defined but the superview instead ? I'll tick your answer in addition if you do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One critical issue I see is your use of `self.center`. Your intent is to move to the center of the view but `self.center` is relative to the view's frame, not its bounds.

Everything in `drawRect:` needs to be relative to the view's bounds, not its frame.

Change this line:

```
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, self.center.x, self.center.y);
```

to:

```
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds));
```

Make a similar change to the call to `CGContextAddArc`.

BTW - the only time `self.center` would work for this case is if the view's origin is at `0, 0`. With any other origin, `self.center` will give you a problem for this case.

Comment: Thanks for clear explanation :D Working nice now. I think the CGContextMoveToPoint() was redundant. I removed it from my code.